# what is the first child node of this div element?

Tags: html, dom, child-nodes

What is the first child node of the 'div' element in this example?

I thought it would be the first 'p' element. It seems to be something else though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">
<p>my first paragraph</p>
<p>my second paragraph</p>
</div>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>


<script>
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").childNodes[0];

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


</script>

</body>
</html>


my first paragraph

my second paragraph

[object Text]

my first paragraph
```

Comment: If there is whitespace then it will be the textnode

Comment: Do some more reading - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-traverse-the-dom#children-nodes

Comment: Likely a `TextNode` with its content being the newline. Print out `children()` of your div to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is whitespace at the beginning of the parent it's `textNode` with whitespace as content. You can check the [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) property([`3` represent text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType#Node_type_constants)) for checking node type.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("myDiv").childNodes[0].nodeType)
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>my first paragraph</p>
  <p>my second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

---

To get only children elements use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) property.

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").children[0].textContent;
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("myDiv").children[0].textContent)
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>my first paragraph</p>
  <p>my second paragraph</p>
</div>
```